# cast function with expression :: types throw mismatched inputs ":" error in Amazon Athena Query Editor

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

According to [Amazon Athena documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html) one should be able to use the syntax *expression :: type* to cast a variable. Trying to run the example on the Query Editor throws an error:

```
select 123.456::decimal(2,1);
>>> line 6:15: mismatched input ':'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AT', '[', '||', <expression>
```

I guess the issues is related to serialization / inputs types. Is there a way (like character escaping) to make it pass and use this convenient syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link is not Athena documentation but Redshift one. Athena is build on top of [Presto](https://prestodb.io/) which supports [`cast`](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/conversion.html) and `try_cast` conversion functions.